# how to remove hyphen from string +xslt

Tags: xslt, substring

how to remove hyphen from string like "19650512-0065" to "196505120065"

using this template : passing theID =

```
   <xsl:template name="unformatLFPartyID">
        <xsl:param name="theID" select="." />

        <xsl:variable name="idSuffix" select="string-length($theID) - 3" />

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($theID,'-')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($theID,0,$idSuffix)" />
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($theID, $idSuffix)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$theID" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Try replacing the xsl:variable and entire xsl:choose with `<xsl:value-of select="translate($theID,'-','')"/>`

Comment: @DanielHaley you should make that an answer not a comment.

Comment: @MichaelKay - I'm always wary of adding answers when I can't test them, especially from my phone, but I suppose this one is simple enough I can risk it :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing the `xsl:variable` and entire `xsl:choose` with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate($theID,'-','')"/>
```